# Long wait time after change server - No consuming of server resources

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, apache-2.4, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trasfering this [website](http://red-live.it/) from *Media Temple* hosting **to Digital Ocean**. I plan to move the website from MT to DO to increases performance, I create a [stage area](http://dev.red-live.it/) on digital ocean. I had 18 seconds of wait time until the browser load the website from DO, according to [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cP1vqo/http://dev.red-live.it/).

Digital ocean hardware are x3 powerful then Mediatemple(shared hosting) and this droplet had only this website(2 GB RAM, 2 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L v3 @ 1.80GHz, 40 GB SSD).

**Debug already done**:

- Switch between PHP version from oldest to newest, actually i'm on version 7.1;
- No timeout detected;
- Slowest query 0.9 sec
- Server load time 0,5 sec
- No php Warning;
- A read a lot of situation similar to mine here on server fault, no solution found (Apache restart, ssl issue, DB issue and caching );
- Test website on localhost, no issue detected.

**Hypothesis #1**:DNS cause waiting issue - I'm on cloudflare and I manage this subdomain from DNS record panel.

**Hypothesis #2**:Mediatemple has polluted the code with proprietary libraries.

**Hypothesis #3**:Apache has an issue when resolve hostname

Comment: I see the long wait on every page. My first thought is that you have a database problem. What database did you use? How did you configure it on your new droplet?

Comment: I'm on MariaDB (10.1.23+maria-1~xenial) managed by runcloud.io with standard config. Do you need cfg? From PMA i cant see performance issue.